# loop shows only one Unicode character

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to take from String all the Unicode characters. 
unfortunately the output shows me only the last one character from String..
For example, if I type: abc, it shows only: 99 (Unicode char of letter c) 
I wish to see outcome like this: 97,98,99

```
 <input type="text" id="task49" class="form-control" placeholder="write something" aria-label=""
                        aria-describedby=" basic-addon2">
                    </br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" onclick="task49()">Check</button>
                    <p class="answer" id="task49ans"></p>
//script
task49 = () => {
    let task49word = document.getElementById("task49").value;
    //let arr = task49word.toLowerCase().split("");
    for (let i = 0; i < task49word.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("task49ans").innerHTML = task49word.charCodeAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: You're overwriting the `.innerHTML` in every iteration.

Comment: Change `=` to `+=`

Comment: For your use case `.textContent` would [suit way better](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML) than `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

You need to append, not overwrite, so use `+=` not `=`. Inside the `for` loop, please change this:

```
document.getElementById("task49ans").innerHTML += task49word.charCodeAt(i);
```

Comment: this will increase the inputvalue. but it should show the charcode of the actual input.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first make a whole string and only then assign it to element's `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("task49ans").innerHTML = 
  task49word.split('').map(l => l.charCodeAt(0)).join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a good idea to call "document.getElementById("task49ans").innerHTML" on each iteration. It seems more appropriate to build the String by concatenating the "Unicode" (.concat) and then passing the result to the "document.getElementById("task49ans").innerHTML"

Answer (score -1):

put it into a second variable like

```
    let task49word = document.getElementById("task49").value;
    let task49ans = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < task49word.length; i++) {
        task49ans +=task49word.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    document.getElementById("task49ans").innerHTML = task49ans;
```